# In regular expressions, how to replace only some instances of an identical string?

Tags: php, regex, string

Basically what I want to do is replace a filename so that

`whatever-[xxx]-[xxx].[xxx]` becomes `whatever-150-150.[xxx]`

so if I have:

`aisuiuhviu123ounsciun-174-345.JPG`  becomes  `aisuiuhviu123ounsciun-150-150.JPG`

and

`wuernicun-123-25.png` becomes `wuernicun-150-150.png`

so far I have got the last bit (file extension) figured out with `/(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/`

but the number part is really confusing basically the file will always be:

`[string]-[2-4 numbers]-[2-4 numbers].[original file extension]`

One day I will get around to reading the entire regex reference but it's baffling to me.

Comment: Whoever -1'd this question, should post a comment with their issue with the question.

Comment: yeah, I thought that was a bit rude too... thanks @HeatfanJohn :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick (assuming the file name is stored in an appropriately named variable):

```
preg_replace("/([^-]+)-\d{2,4}-\d{2,4}\.(.+)/i", "$1-150-150.$2", $filename);
```

What are we doing here? Let's look:

1. We match the first part of the name with `([^-]+)`.
2. Then a dash with `-`.
3. Then a number (between 2 and 4 digits long): `\d{2,4}`
4. Then another dash: `-`
5. Then another number: `\d{2,4}`
6. Then a literal dot: `\.`
7. Then the file extension (which could be whatever): `(.+)`

Note that we use capturing groups in step 1 and 7 so we can use those values in our replacement. It pays to learn regular expressions; they are a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand your question.. but `-[\d]+` should do what you're after. It will match a dash (-) followed by a whole number. Then you just need to replace it with a dash and 150. You don't need to match the extension if you're not going to change it. In fact, you don't need to match anything but the numbers and the dash to accomplish what you need.